# trying to change foreground color of text and getting error "can't implicitly convert type 'string' to 'windows.ui.xaml.Media.Brush'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to change foreground color of text using

```
objNameWritten.Foreground = Headername[currentIndex];
```

syntax in loop but getting error cannot implicitly convert string to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush'.

How to resolve this issue?

XAML

```
string[] Headername = new string[] { "Yellow", "White", "Red", "Purple", "Pink", "Orange", "Green", "Grey", "Brown", "Blue", "Black" };
objNameWritten.Foreground = Headername[currentIndex];
```

C# code

```
private void FwdImgChng(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //if (currentIndex == 11)
    //{ return; }
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex > 10)
    {
        currentIndex = 10;
        return;
    }

    Header.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Header/_0000_header_" + currentIndex + ".png"));
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + currentIndex + "_0.png"));
    prevObjBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Button/prev" + currentIndex + ".png"));
    fwdObjBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Button/next" + currentIndex + ".png"));
    HeaderName.Text = Headername[currentIndex];
    objNameWritten.Text = objnamewritten[currentIndex];
    objNameWritten.Foreground = Headername[currentIndex];
    mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/" + currentIndex + "_0.mp3");
    mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Foreground** can be **SolidColorBrush** as source, you can't put just a string.

You may declare your colors as **Color**:

```
    Color[] Headername =  { Colors.Yellow, Colors.White}; //etc.
```

And then apply to **Foreground**:

```
    objNameWritten.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Headername[currentIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way:

```
objNameWritten.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Headername[currentIndex]);
```

Foreground is Brush object and you are trying to put string there without any conversion

you can put there SolidColorBrush for example:

```
objNameWritten.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(){Color = Colors.Red};
```

but conversion string <=> Color object is up to you (you can use enumeration as above, use Color.FromARGB() method or write your own converter, depending on the input data you want

edit:

on WPF there was method Color.FromName(string name) that would do the exact job you propably want, but it exists no more in UWP